# How can I abort the closing of a dialog in libgdx?

Tags: libgdx

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog("Warning", skin, "dialog") {
    public void result(Object obj) {
        System.out.println("result "+obj);
        if(obj == true) {
            >> abort the dialog closing ? <<
        }
    }
};
dialog.text("Info?");
dialog.button("Yes", true);
dialog.button("No", false);
dialog.key(Keys.Enter, true);
dialog.show();
```

how to abort the closing of the dialog?

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation notes](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Dialog.html#result-java.lang.Object-) that when the `result` method is called, the dialog will be hidden unless [`cancel()`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Dialog.html#cancel--) is called.

So you'll want to invoke `dialog.cancel()` within your result callback somewhere.